# Proving $(a + ab)^*a = a(a + ba)^*$

Tags: regular-expressions

Need to prove $(a + ab)^*a = a(a + ba)^*$ by using regular algebra.

Concatenation does not commute. So repeated use of commutativity will fail. I am getting confused about which identity I should use to prove this. What I can interpret is that I just need to change the side of $a$ but the $^*$ must be kept outside. But I am not able to do this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What identities are you allowed to use?

Comment: @nirshahar regex has huge number of identities. Among them, the fruitful one is difficult to choose.

Comment: Technically speaking, if the question is correct then this is also a valid identity. But clearly, you cant use it. I see someone already gave you a satisfying answer. So there is no need anymore :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an instance of the identity $(xy)^*x = x(yx)^*$ with $x = a$ and $y = 1 + b$:
$$
(a + ab)^* a = (a(1+b))^*a = a((1+b)a)^* = a(a +ba)^*
$$

Comment: Very much elegant. But is this identity very well-known? Bcz if this qus comes in university exam, can I use it directly or I have to prove that identity separately?

Comment: This identity is well-known in my opinion, but it is also very easy to prove. It suffices to prove that the equality $x(yx)^n = x(yx)^n$ holds for all $n \geqslant 0$, but this is just a consequence of the associativity of the product. For instance $x(yx)^2 = xyxyx = (xy)^2x$.

Comment: i think it should be $x(yx)^n = (xy)^nx$ in your comment.

Comment: Of course, you are right !

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't change anything, since comments can't be edited after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Write:

$\begin{align*}
  (a + a b) a
    &= a a + a b a \\
    &= a (a + b a)
\end{align*}$

Thus:

$\begin{align*}
  (a + a b)^n a
    &= (a + a b)^{n - 1} a (a + b a) \\
    &\;\;\vdots \\
    &= a (a + b a)^n
\end{align*}$

Note this is true whatever $n$ may be. So:

$\begin{align*}
   (a + a b)^* a
     &= \left( \bigcup_{n \ge 0} (a + a b)^n \right) a \\
     &= \bigcup_{n \ge 0} (a + a b)^n a \\
     &= \bigcup_{n \ge 0} a (a + b a)^n \\
     &= a \bigcup_{n \ge 0} (a + b a)^n \\
     &= a (a + b a)^*
\end{align*}$

(Not very elegant...)

Comment: Could $a$ commute like that in 2nd line?

Comment: @ManjoyDas, it doesn't. A mistake on my part, fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should write $(a+ab)^*a$ as $\bigcup\limits_{n\geqslant 0}(a+ab)^na$ and try to factorize $(a+ab)^na$ differently from here.

Comment: But it wont derive $a$ anymore... I think you went the wrong way: $(a+ab)^+=(a+ab)^*(a+ab)$ and not the other way around

Comment: @nirshahar My bad, thanks for pointing it out.